# Issue in opening a new GUI on second machine after first machine signals it

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets

I am having a GUI application(windows form in c#) running on both of my windows machine. Both the machines are connected with each other through socket(Asynchronous).
server(2nd machine) is in listening mode.
when user press a button on client (1st machine), then client machine open a new GUI application on itself and signals server machine also.

Now, I am getting the issue on server machine.
If I use **Form.Show()**, I am not able to do anything on the new GUI.
If I use **Form.ShowDialog()**, then in this case once I close the new GUI, my main application crashes on the server machine.
This issue is not observed on client machine.

Here is the code for server machine:

```
    public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            String content = String.Empty;
            StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket handler = state.workSocket;
            int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);
            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                // There  might be more data, so store the data received so far.
                    state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
                    state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));

                // Check for end-of-file tag. If it is not there, read 
                // more data.
                content = state.sb.ToString();
                Logger.DebugLogFile(content);
                if (content.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1)
                {
                    if (content.IndexOf("start") > -1)
                    {
                            Tool_Logging tl = new Tool_Logging();
                            tl.ShowDialog();
                            Send(handler, "<EOF>");
                            Thread.Sleep(100);
                            listener.BeginAccept(
                    new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),
                    listener);
```

Code is crashing at the last line.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a 'Context' issue.

When your 'New GUI' (as you refer to it) form is loaded, keep its context globally:

```
public class NewGUIForm : Form
{
    static System.Threading.SynchronizationContext _context = null;

    ... 

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        _context = WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.Current;
        base.OnLoad(e);
    }

    ...

   public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   {
       ...
       System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback method = new System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback((o) =>
                {
                        Tool_Logging tl = new Tool_Logging();
                        tl.ShowDialog();
                });
       _context.Post(method, input);
       ...
   }

}
```